# R: Convert yearly indicator variables to single year variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has a set of columns which are indicator variables for a given year. For instance, the "d80" column is 1 for rows where the year was 1980 and 0 otherwise.

```
for(i in names(df)[31:35]){
  print(c(i, df[[i]][0:5]))
}

[1] "d80" "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[1] "d81" "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[1] "d82" "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
[1] "d83" "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"  
[1] "d84" "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"
```

Presented another way:

```
head(data$d80)
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0

head(data$d81)
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

and a third way:

```
> x = df[1:3, 31:55]
> dput(x)
structure(list(d80 = c(1L, 0L, 0L), d81 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), d82 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L), d83 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d84 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d85 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), d86 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d87 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d88 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), d89 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d90 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d91 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), d92 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d93 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d94 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), d95 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d96 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d97 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), d98 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d99 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d00 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), d01 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d02 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), d03 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), d04 = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

My ultimate goal is to calculate the average  of a given column across each year, so I'd like to add a column where the value in each row is equal to the year of the row. In other words, I'd like to collapse the set of year indicator columns into a single column. For instance, the data above would become

```
80
81
82
83
84
```

What's the best way to do this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why you don't post that part of your dataset instead of that for loop output? We need to have a sample of your dataset in order to help.

Comment: Thanks for following up. The data set itself is huge, so I put that loop in to grab a representative subset. It's just printing the column name, followed by the first five values. I'll update with the data presented in another way too

Comment: No matter how big it is it should be easy to grab part (i.e. subset) of it based on rows and columns. Check this example `mtcars;
dt = mtcars[1:5, 5:8];
dput(dt)`. If you post the output of `dput(.)` we'll be able to use your data. Makes sense?

Comment: Sounds good. I wasn't familiar with `dput` -- thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataset is `df` you can use this approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(id = row_number()) %>%     # for every row numer (row id)
  nest() %>%                          # nest data
  mutate(year = map(data, ~as.numeric(gsub("d", "", names(.)[.==1])))) %>%  # keep the column name of value 1, remove "d" and make the value numeric 
  unnest() %>%                        # unnest data
  select(-id)                         # remove row id


# # A tibble: 3 x 26
#    year   d80   d81   d82   d83   d84   d85   d86   d87   d88   d89   d90   d91   d92   d93
#   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1    80     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 2    81     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 3    82     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# # ... with 11 more variables: d94 <int>, d95 <int>, d96 <int>, d97 <int>, d98 <int>, d99 <int>,
# #   d00 <int>, d01 <int>, d02 <int>, d03 <int>, d04 <int>
```

The new column is called `year` and it's in the beginning of the dataset.

An alternative way is with a bit of reshaping and joining:

```
library(tidyverse)

# add a row id (useful for reshaping after)
df = df %>% mutate(id = row_number())

df %>%
  gather(year, value, -id) %>%   # reshape data
  filter(value == 1) %>%         # keep 1s
  mutate(year = as.numeric(gsub("d", "", year))) %>%  # update year value
  left_join(df, by="id") %>%     # join back original dataset
  select(-id, -value)            # remove unnecessary columns


#   year d80 d81 d82 d83 d84 d85 d86 d87 d88 d89 d90 d91 d92 d93 d94 d95 d96 d97 d98 d99 d00 d01
# 1   80   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2   81   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 3   82   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#   d02 d03 d04
# 1   0   0   0
# 2   0   0   0
# 3   0   0   0
```

A base R solution would be

```
df$year = as.numeric(gsub("d", "", apply(df , 1, function(x) names(x)[x==1])))
```

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate it